# No route matches "/subscribers/create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I copied this from a book I'm reading and I followed all the instructions but it's giving me No route matches "/subscribers/create" error:

```
def create
    if request.post?
      @subscriber = Subscriber.new(:email => params[:email])
      if @subscriber.save
        @success = "Thank you, You have been subscribed."
      else
        @error = @subscriber.errors.full_messages[0]
      end
    end
```

Please note that the book is written for Rails v2 and I'm using v3.

What's wrong?

Comment: might want to post the code in your `routes.rb` file

Comment: also code of your form in `views/subscribers/new.html.erb` and its partial.

Comment: If you used `resources :subscribers`, the `create` method is invoked by doing a `POST /subscribers`, not `GET /subscribers/create`.

Comment: `Rake routes` will output your routes

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is missing an END.

Also, no need to specify if request.post?

Rails will automatically route a POST request to the create method